# How Swift captures mutable and immutable struct

Tags: swift

I'm confused about how Swift captures mutable and immutable struct

My code downloads images asynchronously, and after the download finish, the completion closure will be called.

In the following code, It prints captured `index` value. The first code will print only `17`. But the second code will print `0 1 2 ... 16`. ( sponsorClass.count == 17 )

---

The firs code is

```
var index = 0
for sponsor in sponsorClass{
    var image = AsynchronousLoadImage( sponsor.imageURL ){ loadedImage in
        println("\(index)") //print 17
    }
    index++
}
```

---

and the second code is

```
var index = 0
for sponsor in sponsorClass{
    let tempIndex = index
    var image = AsynchronousLoadImage( sponsor.imageURL ){ loadedImage in
        println("\(tempIndex)") //print 0,1,2,..,16
    }
    index++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must think of a `var` or `let` statement as **creating** a variable (or constant) **when the statement is executed** in order to understand what's going on. The statement creates a new variable (or constant) each time it's executed.

In your first example, you create a variable named `index` once, before the loop starts. Each closure (you create 17 of them) “closes over” that same `index` variable. This means that each closure **shares** the `index` variable with the outer scope (the block that defines `index`) and all the other closures. There's only one “copy” of `index`, so when you modify it in your loop, each closure sees the modification (when the closure eventually runs).

In your second example, you create a new variable named `tempIndex` on each loop iteration. These 17 variables are independent of each other. Each closure closes over the variable that was created in the same loop iteration as the closure. That is, the closure created while `index == 0` closes over the `tempIndex` that was also created while `index == 0`, and the closure created while `index == 1` closes over the `tempIndex` that was created while `index == 1`, and so on. Thus you create 17 independent variables (each named `tempIndex`), and 17 closures, and each closure closes over a separate variable. Since you never modify any of the 17 `tempIndex` variables after you create them, each closure sees the original value assigned to its corresponding variable.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

Let = immutable var (constant) - value CAN'T be changed.

Var = mutable ( variable) - value CAN be changed.

Comment: In async task you loop will run next round even if first round is still doing some work. Try putting index++ in clousure block ( when you know that image loading was done).